# can iPad run frontend and backend

Tags: swift, ipad, design-patterns, webserver, backend

Let's say one builds an iPad app with the following requirements:

- multiple iPads must be able to have the same state,
- one of the iPads will always be unused by humans and simply connected to a large screen
- Some basic data must be stored for export later,
- iPads may be on the same network

Of course, most developers would use the cloud as the backend location but I p am thinking that one could possibly run the backend web server on the iPad connected to a screen. So, this iPad would be running two things: the app and the web server app. Is this possible? Assume the load is very light.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be stable even if you used one of the many workarounds to keep it alive.